# date format javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

The script below returns dates in this format:

Fri Apr 21 2011 12:18:25 GMT+0200

Fri Apr 22 2011 12:18:25 GMT+0200

Fri Apr 29 2011 12:18:25 GMT+0200

My question is: how to get dates in this format:

dd/mm/year like so: 21/04/2001

```
function addDays(dateObj, numDays) {
   dateObj.setDate(dateObj.getDate() + numDays);
   return dateObj;
}
var now = new Date();
var tomorrow = addDays(new Date(), 1);
var nextWeek = addDays(new Date(), 8);

    {
jQuery("input[id*='now']").val(now);
jQuery("input[id*='tomorrow']").val(tomorrow);
jQuery("input[id*='nextweek']").val(nextWeek);
    }
```

Comment: take a look at : http://www.cev.washington.edu/lc/CLWEBCLB/jst/js_datetime.html

Answer (score 3):

```
var date = new Date();
var d  = date.getDate();
var day = (d < 10) ? '0' + d : d;
var m = date.getMonth() + 1;
var month = (m < 10) ? '0' + m : m;
var yy = date.getYear();
var year = (yy < 1000) ? yy + 1900 : yy;

alert(day + "/" + month + "/" + year);
```

Try this.

Answer (score 1):

```
var d = new Date();
var curr_date = d.getDate();
var curr_month = d.getMonth();
var curr_year = d.getFullYear();
document.write(curr_date + "-" + curr_month + "-" + curr_year);
```

You just may wrap it or use one of the existing helpers

Comment: +1 good answer. I just removed the non-working answer as it doesn't really add anything.

Comment: not a good answer - uses document.write, doesn't pad short numbers, and gets the month wrong too.

Comment: @Alnitak, woops, didn't see the month. Surely you can't criticise `document.write` though - it's merely an example.

Comment: @Box9 that was actually the least important of my complaints. Much of the rest of the answer is simply wrong.

Comment: Sorry, I am new to all this. I forgot to delete the wrong parts. And for sure document.write is just demonstration. @Box9 thanks for cleaning up my post

Comment: i doubt that that works when you want to do var curr_date = d.getDate()+8;

Comment: No, you can't do it this way. If you want to add Days you have to do it before you create the formated string. This is simply a JS native way to archive a custom formated string.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you can use Steve Levithan's dateformat script: http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/date-time-format

Comment: Anyone else have any issues with getting Steve's script working on an iPad? I have it embedded in a mobile app and love, till I just noticed it bombs out in iPad

Answer (score 1):

Check out [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)! It's a really powerful little library for working with Dates in JavaScript.

```
var today = moment(new Date());
today.format("D/M/YYYY");                  // "4/11/2012"
today.format("MMMM D, YYYY h:m A");        // outputs "April 11, 2012 2:42 PM"

// in one line...
moment().format("D/M/YYYY");               // "4/11/2012"
moment().format("MMMM D, YYYY h:m A");     // outputs "April 11, 2012 2:42 PM"
```

Another example...

```
var a = moment([2012, 2, 12, 15, 25, 50, 125]);
a.format("dddd, MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a"); // "Monday, March 12th 2012, 3:25:50 pm"
a.format("ddd, hA");                       // "Mon, 3PM"
```

---

Also, its worth mentioning to checkout [date.js](http://www.datejs.com/). I think the two libraries complement each other.

Answer (score 1):

The formatting library https://github.com/anywhichway/stringformatter will address this issue and more. It supports most of the momentjs formats plus U, G, I, L, T, to return UTC, GTM, ISO, Local, and Time strings respectively. It also provides a consistent approach that can be used for formatting other things.

Format expressions using this library take the form of embedded Javascript objects, e.g.

`format("{Date: {format: 'DD-MMM-YYYY hh:mm:ss:SSS A'}}",new Date('2015-04-12 00:12:23'));`

will return

`"12-Apr-2015 12:12:23:000 AM"`

Answer (score 0):

Using plain old JavaScript, something like this should work:

```
var formatDateString = function(s) {
  var pad = function(x) { return ((x.length<2) ? "0" : "") + x; }
    , dt = new Date("" + s), d, m, y;
  if (dt.getTime()) {
    d = pad(dt.getDate());
    m = pad(dt.getMonth()+1);
    y = dt.getFullYear();
    return [d, m, y].join('/');
  }
  return null;
};
formatDateString("Fri Apr 21 2011 12:18:25 GMT+0200"); // => "21/04/2011"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're already using jquery UI and the date picker

```
var stringDate = $.datepicker.formatDate( 'dd/mm/yy', new Date() );
```

Answer (score -1):

In pure Javascript:

```
function dmy(d) {

    function pad2(n) {
        return (n < 10) ? '0' + n : n;
    }

    return pad2(d.getUTCDate()) + '/' + 
           pad2(d.getUTCMonth() + 1) + '/' +
           d.getUTCFullYear();
}
```